# Inconsistent data in datastore on concurrent writes

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-python

I am having social network application like Twitter where people follow each other. This is my user and friendship model.

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    followers_count = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0, indexed=True)
    following_count = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0, indexed=False)
    created_time = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class Friendship(ndb.Model):
    user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)
    follower = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)
    created_time = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

The problem I am facing is when a user follows 20 people simultaneously during onboarding, the count in user is wrong. It is at 5 or 6 or 7 when it should be 20.

Below is the follow code,

```
user = user_key.get()
follower = follower_key.get()

def incr_counts_in_user():
    user.followers_count += 1
    follower.following_count += 1

@ndb.transactional(retries=10, xg=True)
def run():
    friendship = create_friendship()
    incr_counts_in_user()
    ndb.put_multi([user, follower, friendship])
run()
```

Comment: You haven't said what create_friendship does ?  Any non ancestor query will suffer from eventual consistency issues.  You should consider using a queue to process the friend creations and possible roll forward semantics.  Whilst this article http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Distributed-Transactions-on-App-Engine uses db. rather than ndb, the same approaches can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are not fetching the user inside the transaction. Any data you use for transaction modifications needs to be also read inside the transaction or it's not actually a transaction.

Comment: Ya that was exactly the problem. Fixed it.